# Bottle не может извлечь цифру из скрытого (disabled) поля формы

Tags: html, python

Сделал форму редактирования пользователя, куда, в том числе, передается и ID в базе данных. Список исходных параметров передал в качестве обычного списка `info`

[image: Скриншот формы]

Вот ее HTML-код:

```
<form id="edituser" method="post" action="/user/save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="dbid">ID записи в БД: </label>
                <input form="edituser" type="text" name="dbid" id="dbid" value="{{ info[0] }}" disabled>
                <label for="name">ФИО сотрудника: </label>
                <input form="edituser" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ info[3] }}" required>
                <label for="branch">Отдел: </label>
                <input form="edituser" type="text" name="branch" id="branch" value="{{ info[4] }}" required>
                <label for="uname">Логин: </label>
                <input form="edituser" type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="{{ info[2] }}" required>
                <label for="ugroup">Категория доступа: </label>
                <input form="edituser" type="text" name="ugroup" id="ugroup" value="{{ info[1] }}" required>
                <label for="passwd">Пароль: </label>
                <input form="edituser" type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input form="edituser" type="submit" class="button" name="save" id="save" value="Сохранить">
                    <a href="/manage" class="button" id="cancel">Отмена</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

И сам фрагмент обработки запроса:

```
@get("/user/save")
@post("/user/save")
def save_user():
    current_user = request.get_cookie("account", secret=SECRET)
    user = UserManager(current_user)
    if request.POST.get("save"):
        dbid = int(request.forms.get("dbid"))
        name = (request.forms.get("name")).decode("utf-8")
        branch = (request.forms.get("barnch")).decode("utf-8")
        uname = (request.forms.get("uname")).decode("utf-8")
        ugroup = (request.forms.get("ugroup")).decode("utf-8")
        passwd = (request.forms.get("passwd")).decode("utf-8")
        success_edit = user.edit_user(dbid, ugroup, uname, name, branch, passwd)
        if success_edit:
            redirect("/manage")
        else:
            return "error"
```

При нажатии кнопки "Сохранить", получаю ошибку

```
dbid = int(request.forms.get("dbid")), referer: 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Если закомментировать ошибочную строку, а функции `user.edit_user` вместо `dbid` передать конкретное число (в данном случае 3), то все срабатывает, все данные с формы считываются и записываются в БД.

В чем может быть дело?

`dbid = (request.forms.get("dbid")).decode("utf-8")` - вот так тоже не работает :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело тут в том, что выключенные (`disabled`) [поля не отправляют свое содержимое](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled). Т.е. сам браузер не отправляет (не должен отправлять) информацию, а не вы ее как-то неправильно принимаете. Также почитайте о том какие еще поля не отправляют свои данные [в этом разделе](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls), там есть еще сюрпризы, такие как "выключенный" checkbox также ничего не отправит. Альтернатив тут несколько:

- использовать [`readonly` аттрибут](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#read-only). По такому полю можно клацать мышкой, но нельзя менять и данные отправляются в запросе (т.е. *may be successfull* из спецификации):

`<input form="edituser" type="text" name="dbid" id="dbid" value="{{ info[0] }}" readonly>`

- использовать скрытые поля дублеры c таким же именем, как и основное поле:

`<input form="edituser" type="text" name="dbid" id="dbid" value="{{ info[0] }}" readonly>`
`<input form="edituser" type="hidden" name="dbid" id="dbid_real" value="{{info[0] }}">`